# How to implement and use a .dll or .lib in a Visual C++ Project? [SA-MP Source]

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, libraries, multiplayer

I am trying to learn more about Multiplayer Modifications so i've downloaded the source code of San Andreas Multiplayer.

My problem is that the client project creates a .dll and a .lib files. I've searched on many sites how to implement them into a new project but i just did not find a clear answer.

So i am creating a new Visual C++ project where i need to implement the libraries resulted from SAMP Client compilation. Any help would be great :).

If you want you can join me in this project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how SAMP dlls are but in general, this is how it works:

- Linker need *.lib files. So you should copy lib files to your default lib directories or create a new directory under libraries of your project and copy them in it.
- If the project you want to link have `include` files too, do what you did for `lib` files for `include` files too. Copy them to `include` directory.
- Put DLLs in a directory that your application can reach. This can be your Debug folder or even it can be `Windows` or `System32` directory. Choose where to put them on your own (it depends on many parameters. Pick one that fits you).

[This link](http://blog.gockelhut.com/2009/11/visual-studio-2010-property-sheets-and.html) tells you how to put them in project directories.

That's it. You can call functions of the project you want to use. Tell me if you got problem.